# Send HTTP Requests in Background Mode (iOS) Periodically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, background-process

I'm developing a great feature for my app which requires HTTP requests to be sent periodically in background.

I have read already many articles and discussions here, but haven't come up with a solution because all suggestions I met on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) solve the problem only partially.

Let me explain in details what do I want my application to do.

Consider there is a website with API and I want to send requests (when app is in background mode) periodically to check the state of data on the website. And if the state of data is acceptable I would send Push Notification to user to notify him that data is correct at the moment.

Could someone propose a solution how to implement this idea in iOS app?

Comment: Check the prefetch feature: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1771763-prefetchdatasource.

Comment: @MaxPevsner thanks, but in my opinion this approach is absolutely not applicable in the situation. And I need some sort of "software design" answer - not connected with some tools.

Comment: Silent Push notification, once are received on the device you can do some tasks. Full background mode is only available for specific functionalities https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iOS you can't do this, as you've described it. You don't get to schedule tasks to happen at regular intervals when your app is in the background or not running. You also don't get to control whether iOS decides to terminate your app when it's running in the background, so "not running" is a case you'd need to handle (you can't just keep running in the background as for long as you want).

I'm not sure I understand the server side of things though. If your server is manipulating the data until it's acceptable, and it can send push notifications, why does it need to wait for an incoming request from the phone? Why not just send the push when the data is ready? If the app decides what's "acceptable", maybe have the app tell the server what it wants so that the server knows when to send a push.

There are a couple of options that would get close to what you describe. If you implement the "background fetch" feature in your app, iOS will launch the app when it's not running and let it make network calls in the background. There's no guarantee of how often this happens, though. This is described in [Apple's background execution docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

The other option is the "silent" push notification. If your server sends one of these, iOS can launch the app in the background to handle the notification. The app could make a network call if necessary. You can send these at whatever time you like, but Apple warns to not overdo it:

> Silent notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in the background, nor are they meant for high priority updates. APNs treats silent notifications as low priority and may throttle their delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to send more than a few notifications per hour.

Silent pushes are described in [Apple's push notification docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html).

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation!

The problem is that I don't have my own server -- I just can send requests to a service and get responses.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Background Execution Limits**

`Questions`

How do I keep my app running continuously in the background?

If I schedule a timer, how do I get it to fire when the screen is locked?

How do I run code in the background every 15 minutes?

How do I set up a network server that runs in the background?

How can my app provide an IPC service to another one of my app while it’s in the background?

`Answer from Apple:`

The short answer to all of these is You can’t. iOS puts strict limits on background execution. Its default behavior is to suspend your app shortly after the user has moved it to the background; this suspension prevents the process from running any code.

`Official:` https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525