# Http request to server not working on background mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, background-process

Please follow the code. HTTP request are not working in background mode in ionic.

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
            text: 'Doing heavy tasks.'
        });
        // Enable background mode
        this.backgroundMode.enable();
        // Called when background mode has been activated
        this.backgroundMode.isActive(); // => boolean

        this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(() => {
            console.log('Print console for background');
            setInterval(function(){
                // http request (post method)
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can't do this, as you've described it. And for android it will also the app will not be in the background if app removed from memory. Even though you will keep the app in the background it is not a good idea, it will drain your battery.

If your server is manipulating the data until it's acceptable, and it can send push notifications, why does it need to wait for an incoming request from the phone? Why not just send the push when the data is ready? If the app decides what's "acceptable", maybe have the app tell the server what it wants so that the server knows when to send a push.

This is how native apps work for android and iOS. Manage and achieve your requirement using push notification.

[Send HTTP Requests in Background Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920700/9739044)